# Ext.toast render speed

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm using [`Ext.toast`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/Ext.window.Toast.html) to render a message to the user (typically "data saved!"), but the speed at which the message is displayed and disappears is, to me, glacial.

I can't readily see any sort of config option or other property that allows for the display to be sped up, other than vague references to `Ext.fx.Anim`, which doesn't provide any tangible assistance - is there a config or property to speed the animation up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `slideInDuration`, like:

```
Ext.override(Ext.window.Toast, {
    slideInDuration: 1
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cnt

Comment: I've actually managed to find the private properties after posting this, and tbh its probably easier to declare the properties when creating the toast message rather than adding an override to the message. Still makes no sense why this sort of functionality is hidden by default, it should be fairly standard. There are also other properties like `autoCloseDelay` which controls the overall display time, which helps in speeding the message up.